# Angularjs with ng-repeat to print data separate by ,

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have data in json format, which I would like to display the item on the different data cell based on its first element. If more than one element in the cell, multiple item should be shown separable by "," or .

For example, if my json is:

```
data = {{"Mon","012"},{"Tue","123"},{"Mon","112"},{"Mon","032"},...}


<table>
 <tr>
   <td id="Mon"> 012 , 112 , 032 </td>
   <td> id="TUe"> 123 </td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

or

```
<pre>
<table>
 <tr>
   <td id="Mon"> <div>012</div> <div> 112 </div> <div>032</div> </td>
   <td id="TUe"> <div>123</div> </td>
 </tr>
</table>
</pre>
```

I was investigating the doc for ng-repeat with $odd and $index etc., but could not find the right way to get my result.

Comment: Maybe you should first group your data by key (mon, tue, etc) ?

Comment: this is not correct json format.

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON is invalid, so I reformated it a bit to answer the format question.
CSS should do the formatting. You can define a delimiter if there are multiple `<span>` elements.

```
td span+span:before {
  content: ", ";
}
```

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .run(function($rootScope) {
    $rootScope.dataOrdered = [{
      key: "Mon",
      values: ["012", "112", "032"]
    }, {
      key: "Tue",
      values: ["123"]
    }];



  });
```

```css
table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 2px;
}
td span+span:before {
  content: ", ";
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>



<table ng-app="app">
  <tr>
    <td ng-repeat="item in dataOrdered" id="{item.id}}"><span ng-repeat="value in item.values" ng-bind="value"></span>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I am new to web development. Yes. You all are correct. It is not a json. If I have the data structure like the one I show (Array?) .  Do I need to restructure my data first before using the ng-repeat to get the information to display as I need?

Comment: Yes, you need to restructure your data. Simply because it's an invalid syntax. It doesn't matter if JSON or Javascript object/array.